# Need css for half filled circle with complete border

Tags: css

I want css for half filled circle with round border.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOQxF.png)

Comment: Then you'll need to post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you can achieve it in CSS.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px; width:50px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.two{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px; width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
#circle {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid black 3px;
}


#p1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: solid black 2px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="circle">
        <div id="p1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```