# Need CSS for half filled Circle (at the bottom) with border

Tags: html, css, sass

I have already refered to this url and tried to tweak it but wasn't able to get it to work. 
[Need css for half filled circle with complete border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514884/need-css-for-half-filled-circle-with-complete-border)

I need css for below style (bottom half of circle filled)

[image]

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid #ffa500;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div>div {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0;
}

div>div:nth-child(n+2) {
  background: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of the code you linked. Basically you just need to invert the width and height of the inner elements.
I also changed their width / height to percentages to make it a bit more flexible.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one{
  background-color: white;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.two{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

And here's another version, if you really don't want the white line between the border and the bottom half.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.ring {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 8px orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="ring"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the same thing. The problem was that the width and height of my circle is very small. 22px.  It worked for me for 100px. But not for 22 px. I will try your code and see incase I missed something.

Comment: Oh great this solution works too. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Cool - glad to hear it. Happy to help.